# JSON.NET not converting ISO 8601 time to Noda Time Instant

Tags: c#, datetime, json.net, nodatime

The output of the code below is `1970-01-01T00:00:00Z` rather than `2021-09-20T19:43:15Z`. What am I doing wrong? I'm using version 3.0.5 of `NodaTime` and version 3.0.0 of `NodaTime.Serialization.JsonNet`.

```
class Program
    {
        class Foo
        {
            [JsonProperty("time")]
            public Instant Time { get; }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            const string json = "{\"time\": \"2021-09-20T19:43:15.204Z\"}";
            var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(json,
                new JsonSerializerSettings().ConfigureForNodaTime(DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb));
            Console.WriteLine(foo.Time);
        }
    }
```

Thanks for any help,

Jack

Answer (score 3):

Your `Time` property only has a "getter" - no setter. Just change the property to have a setter too:

```cs
[JsonProperty("time")]
public Instant Time { get; set; }
```

Comment: Ah, stupid mistake! Thanks a lot Jon. Is there any way to get warned of this mistake by Json.NET?

Comment: @jackdry: I don't know, I'm afraid.

Comment: @jackdry There was a problem a while ago with getter-only properties, now solved like you see. You can add a custom ContractResolver to the settings. You probably just need to override `CreateProperty`; e.g., (in the overridden method): `var prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization); if (prop != null && !prop.Writable) { throw new JsonException("Property Getter only"); } return prop;`

Comment: The millisecond part of the time is cut off though?

Comment: @vicNeo: This sounds like a different problem (if it's a problem at all, in fact - I suspect it's a misdiagnosis, but we'll see). Please create a new question with a [mcve].

Comment: @JonSkeet indeed, in my debug window it does not show the milliseconds, but "underneath", like under its non-public members, duration has the milliseconds and thus it is not "cut off" really.

Comment: @vicNeo: Again, please create a new question if there's anything still to answer. This seems to be *completely* unrelated to this question.